# Extract String From Files In Directory And Assign It To Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have 3 Excel files in a folder called:

- FY18_Msft Cloud_test.xlsm
- FY19_Msft Cloud_test.xlsm
- FY20_Msft Cloud_test.xlsm

They all have a sheet called "Digital" and I want to merge the data from the three files into a new data frame which I've done with the code below. However, then I also want to add two new columns: one called "Channel" that will read "Digital" for all files and another one called "Fiscal" that will read "FY18" for the data taken from the first file, FY19 from the second file and FY20 from the third file.

I have the for loop below and while I manage to get the get the data merge and the Channel okay I can't figure out a way to add the correct fiscal against each data entry. I extract the name of the fiscal from the file name by taking the string before the first underscore.

```
digital_df = pd.DataFrame()
os.chdir(plans_folder)

            for infile in glob.glob(plans_folder + "*Msft Cloud*.xlsm"):
                for fiscal in glob.glob("*Msft Cloud*.xlsm"):
                    data_digital = pd.read_excel(infile, sheetname="Digital", skiprows=9)
                    data_digital.insert(0, "Channel", "Digital")
                    digital_df = digital_df.append(data_digital, ignore_index=True)
                    fiscal = fiscal.split('_', 1)[0]
                    digital_df['Fiscal'] = fiscal

digital_df
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to get your information more easily - from a full filepath, this reports the name of the file (usually!).

So you could do the following (assuming you've already imported `os`). Note you can simplify your loops - you previously did both `infile` and `fiscal` which were effectively returning the same list of files, meaning you;d get each of the four files four times! Also, it's much easier to add the fiscal year before merging the DataFrames:

```
for infile in glob.glob(plans_folder + "*Msft Cloud*.xlsm"):
    data_digital = pd.read_excel(infile, sheetname="Digital", skiprows=9)
    data_digital["Channel"] = "Digital"
    f_year = os.path.basename(infile).split('_')[0]
    data_digital["Fiscal"] = f_year
    digital_df = digital_df.append(data_digital, ignore_index=True)
```

As an aside, if you're using `os.path.basename()` in this way, you don't *need* to change into the directory (with `os.chdir`)

To write this dataframe to a csv, you can use the `to_csv()` method of a DataFrame:

```
digital_df.to_csv(os.path.join(plans_folder, 'Summary.csv'), index=False)
```

This should overwrite any existing file, and using `os.path.join` ensures we end up in the same folder as the files.

Comment: Thanks that worked! However now it's quadruplicating the data for some odd reason so the data is repeated four times for each fiscal...

Comment: you loop over `infile in glob.glob(plans_folder + "*Msft Cloud*.xlsm")` and `fiscal in glob.glob("*Msft Cloud*.xlsm")` - you shoul donly do one. I'll edit it in

Comment: Still not working. FY18 is duplicating 7 times and FY19 seven times... And there's also ~$FY18 as an option for fiscal for some reason but I can filter that out if need be.

Comment: Have extra files been added to your folder, possibly from the previous runs? Note that `glob` will return all files matching the naming convention.

Comment: Ah I see what the problem was, every time I run the program again it copies the same data on top of the previous data frame - hence why the repetition. Still no idea where the ~$FY18 comes from. Amazing, thank you very much!

Comment: Excel sometimes creates a temporary file starting with ~$ when you have a file open. Did you perhaps have the FY18 file open in Excel while running the script?

Comment: Ah yeah, well spotted! Sorry for the stupid question but is there a way to make the script run from scratch so I avoid duplication? Anyway thanks so much again for your help

Comment: No worries! How are you writing out the dataframe? To a csv? To Excel?

Comment: The output is to a csv

Comment: It's giving me an error: join() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: Sorry! Missed the closing bracket after the filename, corrected now

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly now.

Comment: That's great! If everything is working properly, you can mark the answer as "correct" by clicking the green arrow next to it.